# how to create own traits migration in yii2

Tags: yii2

This is a default code for migration

```
<?php

use yii\db\Schema;
use yii\db\Migration;

class m150101_185401_create_news_table extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('news', [
            'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
            'title' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
            'content' => Schema::TYPE_TEXT,
        ]);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('news');
    }
}
```

here TYPE_TEXT is a predefined trait ,
so how i can create my own trait for example 
int(11) Not NULL unsigned to unsignedInt is there any way to create own traits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can define your personalSchemaBuilderTraits in a proper namespace  and the recall this in your code

look at this yii2 doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-schemabuildertrait.html

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/Migration.php

In Migration.php  you can easly view in the firt line  the call for use ....

In yii\db\SchemaBuilderTrait you can see the functions for settinge the value of the several column data type. This is the preferred method for create column from version 2.0.6